# Delete multiple emails (articles)

Tags: gnus, email

In Gnus, in summary buffer, how would one delete multiple emails (not retire, but actually delete). Deleting singe email (article) is <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> (or similar), but this doesn't seem to work on any kind of marking I was able to come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the articles to be deleted with `#`.

Comment: Do you have a link or bound function name? That's not covered on the gnus marking info page. (or I can't find it).

Comment: Appears to work! thank you so much. @RichieHH it is bound to `gnus-summary-mark-as-processable`, and this is its manual page: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Setting-Process-Marks.html . Though I wouldn't have been able to find this on my own.